# Can we find the meaning of Sandyavandanam In our local convenient language?

Tags: practice, brahmins, sandhyavandanam, bramhacharya

Brahmins do Sandyavandanam mugging the book. How do we understand or know the meaning of the mantras we chant?

Only those who is master in Sanskrit can understand, rest they just chant full book.

Is there a translation available or a book available for example in Kannada language?

I am surprised to see modifications in Sandyavandanam mantras a little in Yajurveda. When i had Bramhopadesham before 20years, the mantras from the same publication was different compared to now.

Comment: The following is a Sandhya manual and it is in Kannada .. so may be helpful for you -- https://ia600901.us.archive.org/30/items/Yajurveda_Trikala_Sandhyavandana_-_Vadirajacharya_Karnam/Yajurveda%20Trikala%20Sandhyavandana%20-%20Vadirajacharya%20Karnam.pdf

Comment: In Bengal we easily get books like Yajurvedi Sandhya, Rig Vedi Sandhya etc. in Bengali language. So it should be easy for you too to get the needed book in Kannada from the local book shops?